# Save Dataframe to csv directly to s3 Python

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3, dataframe, boto3

I have a pandas DataFrame that I want to upload to a new CSV file. The problem is that I don't want to save the file locally before transferring it to s3. Is there any method like to_csv for writing the dataframe to s3 directly? I am using boto3.
Here is what I have so far:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='key', aws_secret_access_key='secret_key')
read_file = s3.get_object(Bucket, Key)
df = pd.read_csv(read_file['Body'])

# Make alterations to DataFrame

# Then export DataFrame to CSV through direct transfer to s3
```

Comment: `df.to_csv('s3://mybucket/dfs/somedf.csv')`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56275519/908886 for more info.

Comment: I love this solution. So tight, compact, and elegant! Thanks for sharing!!

Comment: @PeterBerg it's giving me access denied error :(

Answer (score 269, accepted):

You can use:

```
from io import StringIO # python3; python2: BytesIO 
import boto3

bucket = 'my_bucket_name' # already created on S3
csv_buffer = StringIO()
df.to_csv(csv_buffer)
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_resource.Object(bucket, 'df.csv').put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
```

In addition, `pandas` now also [handles reading and writing remote files](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#reading-writing-remote-files) via [fspec](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), if installed. In other words, in this case `df.to_csv('s3://bucket/folder/path/file.csv)` also works.

Comment: from io import StringIO , so doesn't seem to allow edits less than 6 characters.

Comment: If this is a large file, what does this do to memory...?

Comment: If the file is bigger then the RAM you have available the action will fail and will except an Exception (don't know which one). This should be accepted as answer

Comment: I got `TypeError: unicode argument expected, got 'str'` error while using `StringIO`. I used `BytesIO` and it worked perfectly fine. _Note: this was in Python 2.7_

Comment: what is `bucket` object? how did you create that?

Comment: `bucket` is where you store objects on S3. The code assumes you have already created the destination (think: directory) where to store this. See [S3 docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html)

Comment: something like : bucket= s3_resource.Bucket('bucket_name') ?

Comment: Got error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

Comment: I got Access Denied for a while because the bucket was using different access keys than my default. If this is the case, then you need to also specify the S3 session with this snippet of code before calling the session.resource(): 
session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=<AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID>,
        aws_secret_access_key=<AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>,
    )

Comment: This works, but changes the owner of the files to my account. Is there a way to keep the Bucket owner as the owner of the written files?

Comment: Where the content of dataframe? like df_csv = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['text'])

Comment: is this approach thread safe ? want to run this in multi-threaded environment

Comment: my script runs fine with no errors but the file never uploads

Comment: While this used to be a fine answer, the more concise / easier answer is now here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56275519/12678216

Answer (score 163):

You can directly use the S3 path. I am using [Pandas 0.24.1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/index.html#version-0-24)

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame( [ [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2] ], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  2  2  2

In [4]: df.to_csv('s3://experimental/playground/temp_csv/dummy.csv', index=False)

In [5]: pd.__version__
Out[5]: '0.24.1'

In [6]: new_df = pd.read_csv('s3://experimental/playground/temp_csv/dummy.csv')

In [7]: new_df
Out[7]:
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  2  2  2
```

**[Release Note:](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.20.0.html#s3-file-handling)**

> **S3 File Handling**
>
> pandas now uses s3fs for handling S3 connections. This shouldn’t break any code. However, since s3fs is not a required dependency, you will need to install it separately, like boto in prior versions of pandas. [GH11915](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11915).

Comment: this is definitely the easiest answer now, it uses s3fs behind the scenes so you need to add that to your requirements.txt

Comment: I like it is easy, but it seems it's not really working since I keep getting the following error ```NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials```. Any suggestions?

Comment: I can confirm this does not work with pandas <= 0.23.4, so be sure to upgrade to pandas 0.24

Comment: This is the error i see when i try to use to_csv command
TypeError: write() argument 1 must be unicode, not str

Comment: I'm using pandas 0.24.2 and what I get is `NotImplementedError: Text mode not supported, use mode='wb' and manage bytes`. any suggestions?

Comment: When I use this code , the rows in the CSV file in S3 every line was skipped , what could be the solution ?

Comment: This is great if you're using AWS Lambda to execute your code too BTW. Just create a lambda layer with the install files for pandas and s3fs, and you're good to go: direct communication with buckets in your AWS instance.

Comment: if you want to use AWS Profiles (IAM roles) you just:
`df.to_csv(path_or_buf="s3://your-bucket/key/df.csv", storage_options={"profile":"your-profile-name"})`

Comment: This link shows clearly how to pass credentials for pandas API which uses s3fs https://towardsdatascience.com/reading-and-writing-files-from-to-amazon-s3-with-pandas-ccaf90bfe86c

Comment: I'm getting an error `AttributeError: 'AioClientCreator' object has no attribute '_register_lazy_block_unknown_fips_pseudo_regions'` when I try to do it this way (this is with fsspec and s3fs installed).

Comment: This work when working from AWS SageMaker Studio notebooks: `df.to_csv(f"s3://{bucket}/{prefix}/data.csv", index=False, header=False)`, without having to manually add some other dependencies.

Comment: Per @jason's [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/reading-and-writing-files-from-to-amazon-s3-with-pandas-ccaf90bfe86c), you can pass credentials/keys using the storage_options parameter (in pandas v.1.2.0+):  

`aws_credentials = { "key": "***", "secret": "***", "token": "***" }
df.to_csv("s3://...", index=False, storage_options=aws_credentials)`

or use one of the methods from s3fs here: 
https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#credentials

Answer (score 73):

I like [s3fs](http://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which lets you use s3 (almost) like a local filesystem.

You can do this:

```
import s3fs

bytes_to_write = df.to_csv(None).encode()
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(key=key, secret=secret)
with fs.open('s3://bucket/path/to/file.csv', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(bytes_to_write)
```

`s3fs` supports only `rb` and `wb` modes of opening the file, that's why I did this `bytes_to_write` stuff.

Comment: Great! How can I get the file url using same s3fs module?

Comment: I was looking for the URL from where I can download the written file, anyways I get that via S3FileSystem. Thanks

Comment: this is what i use; thanks. I am curious why pd.read_csv(<s3path>) works as expected but for writing we have to use this work around.. except in the case that i'm writing directly to the s3 bucket my jupyter is in.

Comment: @michcio1234 how can i do the same in append mode ? I need to append the data in existing csv on s3

Comment: @j' `s3fs` doesn't seem to support append mode.

Answer (score 57):

This is a more up to date answer:

```
import s3fs

s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False)

# Use 'w' for py3, 'wb' for py2
with s3.open('<bucket-name>/<filename>.csv','w') as f:
    df.to_csv(f)
```

The problem with StringIO is that it will eat away at your memory. With this method, you are streaming the file to s3, rather than converting it to string, then writing it into s3. Holding the pandas dataframe and its string copy in memory seems very inefficient.

If you are working in an ec2 instant, you can give it an IAM role to enable writing it to s3, thus you dont need to pass in credentials directly. However, you can also connect to a bucket by passing credentials to the `S3FileSystem()` function. See documention:https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: For some reason when I did this every line was skipped in the output CSV

Comment: hmm. not sure why that would happen. perhaps try with another pandas df to see if you still get the problem? If your version of pandas supports it, try @amit-kushwaha 's answer, where you pass the s3 url directly to  `to_csv()`. seems like a cleaner implementation.

Comment: @erncyp I seem to be getting there error: `botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied`  ... I have even made the bucket PUBLIC READ and I have added the following Actions, under my specific account IAM user, in the Bucket Policy:`"Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ]`

Comment: seems like you are lacking the permissions? Make sure to attach S3 read write permissions to the IAM role you are using

Comment: @erncyp I have AdministratorAccess policy attached to my IAM user, so in theory I should be able to read/write just fine... 

Oddly, I am able to write just fine when I use the following function I made, using another StackOverflow user's advice (fyi semi-colons are end-of-line since i dont know how to format in comment section):
`def send_to_bucket(df, fn_out, bucketname):
    csv_buffer = StringIO();
    df.to_csv(csv_buffer);
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3');
    s3_resource.Object(bucketname, fn_out).put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue());`

Comment: @erncyp got it to work, it was an IDE issue with PyCharm, super weird.  Worked in terminal but didnt work in iPython terminal via PyCharm. Needed to restart the kernel and then it worked. Super weird.

Comment: is s3fs approach thread safe ?

Comment: I get "botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials"

Comment: when I tried this I get: OSError: [Errno 22] The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema. did anyone managed to solve it?

Answer (score 17):

If you pass `None` as the first argument to [`to_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) the data will be returned as a string. From there it's an easy step to upload that to S3 in one go.

It should also be possible to pass a `StringIO` object to `to_csv()`, but using a string will be easier.

Comment: Will be easier in which way? What is the correct way to do it ?

Comment: @EranMoshe: either way will work correctly, but obviously it's easier to pass `None` to `to_csv()` and use the returned string than it is to create a `StringIO` object and then read the data back out.

Comment: As a lazy programmer that's what I did. And you meant easier for the programmer who writes less code :>

Answer (score 17):

You can also use the [AWS Data Wrangler](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler):

```py
import awswrangler as wr
    
wr.s3.to_csv(
    df=df,
    path="s3://...",
)
```

Note that it will handle multipart upload for you to make the upload faster.

Answer (score 13):

I found this can be done using `client` also and not just `resource`.

```
from io import StringIO
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client("s3",\
                  region_name=region_name,\
                  aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,\
                  aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)
csv_buf = StringIO()
df.to_csv(csv_buf, header=True, index=False)
csv_buf.seek(0)
s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Body=csv_buf.getvalue(), Key='path/test.csv')
```

Answer (score 5):

I use [AWS Data Wrangler](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler). For example:

```py
import awswrangler as wr
import pandas as pd

# read a local dataframe
df = pd.read_parquet('my_local_file.gz')

# upload to S3 bucket
wr.s3.to_parquet(df=df, path='s3://mys3bucket/file_name.gz')
```

The same applies to csv files. Instead of `read_parquet` and `to_parquet`, use `read_csv` and `to_csv` with the proper file extension.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

- pandas
- boto3
- s3fs (version ≤0.4)

I use `to_csv` with `s3://` in path and `storage_options`

```py
key = "folder/file.csv"

df.to_csv(
    f"s3://{YOUR_S3_BUCKET}/{key}",
    index=False,
    storage_options={
        "key": AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        "secret": AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        "token": AWS_SESSION_TOKEN,
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

since you are using `boto3.client()`, try:

```
import boto3
from io import StringIO #python3 
s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='key', aws_secret_access_key='secret_key')
def copy_to_s3(client, df, bucket, filepath):
    csv_buf = StringIO()
    df.to_csv(csv_buf, header=True, index=False)
    csv_buf.seek(0)
    client.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Body=csv_buf.getvalue(), Key=filepath)
    print(f'Copy {df.shape[0]} rows to S3 Bucket {bucket} at {filepath}, Done!')

copy_to_s3(client=s3, df=df_to_upload, bucket='abc', filepath='def/test.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from io import StringIO
import boto3
#Creating Session With Boto3.
session = boto3.Session(
aws_access_key_id='<your_access_key_id>',
aws_secret_access_key='<your_secret_access_key>'
)
#Creating S3 Resource From the Session.
s3_res = session.resource('s3')
csv_buffer = StringIO()
df.to_csv(csv_buffer)
bucket_name = 'stackvidhya'
s3_object_name = 'df.csv'
s3_res.Object(bucket_name, s3_object_name).put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
print("Dataframe is saved as CSV in S3 bucket.")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To handle large files efficiently you can also use an open-source S3-compatible MinIO, with its `minio` [python client package](https://pypi.org/project/minio/), like in this function of mine:

```
import minio
import os
import pandas as pd

minio_client = minio.Minio(..)

def write_df_to_minio(df, 
                    minio_client, 
                    bucket_name, 
                    file_name="new-file.csv",
                    local_temp_folder="/tmp/", 
                    content_type="application/csv",
                    sep=",",
                    save_row_index=False):

    df.to_csv(os.path.join(local_temp_folder, file_name), sep=sep, index=save_row_index)
    
    minio_results = minio_client.fput_object(bucket_name=bucket_name,
                                             object_name=file_name,
                                             file_path=os.path.join(local_temp_folder, file_name),
                                             content_type=content_type)

    assert minio_results.object_name == file_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to do this with [cloudpathlib](https://cloudpathlib.drivendata.org/stable/), which supports S3 and also Google Cloud Storage and Azure Blob Storage. See example below.

```py
import pandas as pd
from cloudpathlib import CloudPath

# read data from S3
df = pd.read_csv(CloudPath("s3://covid19-lake/rearc-covid-19-testing-data/csv/states_daily/states_daily.csv"))

# look at some of the data
df.head(1).T.iloc[:10]
#>                                       0
#> date                           20210307
#> state                                AK
#> positive                        56886.0
#> probableCases                       NaN
#> negative                            NaN
#> pending                             NaN
#> totalTestResultsSource  totalTestsViral
#> totalTestResults              1731628.0
#> hospitalizedCurrently              33.0
#> hospitalizedCumulative           1293.0

# writing to S3
with CloudPath("s3://bucket-you-can-write-to/data.csv").open("w") as f:
    df.to_csv(f)

CloudPath("s3://bucket-you-can-write-to/data.csv").exists()
#> True
```

Note, that you can't call `df.to_csv(CloudPath("s3://drivendata-public-assets/test-asdf2.csv"))` directly because of the way pandas handles paths/handles passed to it. Instead you need to open the file for writing and pass that handle directly to `to_csv`.

This comes with a few added benefits in terms of setting [particular options](https://cloudpathlib.drivendata.org/stable/other_client_settings/) or [different authentication mechanisms](https://cloudpathlib.drivendata.org/stable/authentication/) or keeping a [persistent cache](https://cloudpathlib.drivendata.org/stable/caching/) so you don't always need to redownload from S3.

Answer (score -5):

I read a csv with two columns from bucket s3, and the content of the file csv i put in pandas dataframe.

Example:

config.json

```
{
  "credential": {
    "access_key":"xxxxxx",
    "secret_key":"xxxxxx"
}
,
"s3":{
       "bucket":"mybucket",
       "key":"csv/user.csv"
   }
}
```

cls_config.json

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import json

class cls_config(object):

    def __init__(self,filename):

        self.filename = filename


    def getConfig(self):

        fileName = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), self.filename)
        with open(fileName) as f:
        config = json.load(f)
        return config
```

cls_pandas.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pandas as pd
import io

class cls_pandas(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def read(self,stream):

        df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(stream), sep = ",")
        return df
```

cls_s3.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import boto3
import json

class cls_s3(object):

    def  __init__(self,access_key,secret_key):

        self.s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)

    def getObject(self,bucket,key):

        read_file = self.s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        body = read_file['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
        return body
```

test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from cls_config import *
from cls_s3 import *
from cls_pandas import *

class test(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.conf = cls_config('config.json')

    def process(self):

        conf = self.conf.getConfig()

        bucket = conf['s3']['bucket']
        key = conf['s3']['key']

        access_key = conf['credential']['access_key']
        secret_key = conf['credential']['secret_key']

        s3 = cls_s3(access_key,secret_key)
        ob = s3.getObject(bucket,key)

        pa = cls_pandas()
        df = pa.read(ob)

        print df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = test()
    test.process()
```

Comment: please don't just post the solution, add an explanation of it too.

Comment: Is there any advantage on making such a complex (for a newbie in Python) solution?

Comment: This reads a file from s3, the question was how to write a df to s3.