# Write Pandas Dataframe to_csv StringIO instead of file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv, boto3

Objective of this code is to read an existing CSV file from a specified S3 bucket into a Dataframe, filter the dataframe for desired columns, and then write the *filtered* Dataframe to a CSV object using StringIO that I can upload to a different S3 bucket.

Everything works right now *except* the code block for the function "prepare_file_for_upload". Below is the full code block:

```
from io import StringIO
import io #unsued at the moment
import logging
import pandas as pd
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

FORMAT = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format=FORMAT)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

#S3 parameters
source_bucket = 'REPLACE'
source_folder = 'REPLACE/'
dest_bucket = 'REPLACE'
dest_folder = 'REPLACE'
output_name = 'REPLACE'

def get_file_name():
try:
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    logging.info(f'Determining filename from: {source_bucket}/{source_folder}')
    bucket_path = s3.list_objects(Bucket=source_bucket, Prefix=source_folder)
    file_name =[key['Key'] for key in bucket_path['Contents']][1]
    logging.info(file_name)
    return file_name
except ClientError as e:
    logging.info(f'Unable to determine file name from bucket {source_bucket}/{source_folder}')
    logging.info(e)

def get_file_data(file_name):
try:
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    logging.info(f'file name from get data: {file_name}')
    obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=source_bucket, Key=file_name)
    body = obj['Body']
    body_string = body.read().decode('utf-8')
    file_data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(body_string))
    #logging.info(file_data)
    return file_data
except ClientError as e:
    logging.info(f'Unable to read {file_name} into datafame')
    logging.info(e)

def filter_file_data(file_data):
try:
    all_columns = list(file_data.columns)
    columns_used = ('col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3')
    desired_columns = [x for x in all_columns if x in columns_used]
    filtered_data = file_data[desired_columns]
    logging.info(type(filtered_data)) #for testing
    return filtered_data
except Exception as e:
    logging.info('Unable to filter file')
    logging.info(e)
```

The block below is where I am attempting to write the existing DF that was passed to the function using "to_csv" method with StringIO instead of creating a local file. to_csv will write to a local file but does not work with buffer (yes, I tried putting the buffer cursor to start position after and still nothing)

```
def prepare_file_for_upload(filtered_data): #this is the function block where I am stuck
try:
    buffer = StringIO()
    output_name = 'FILE_NAME.csv'
    #code below is writing to file but can not get to write to buffer
    output_file = filtered_data.to_csv(buffer, sep=',')
    df = pd.DataFrame(buffer) #for testing
    logging.info(df) #for testing
    return output_file
except Exception as e:
    logging.info(f'Unable to prepare {output_name} for upload')
    logging.info(e)

def upload_file(adjusted_file):
try:
    #dest_key = f'{dest_folder}/{output_name}'
    dest_key = f'{output_name}'
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3.meta.client.upload_file(adjusted_file, dest_bucket, dest_key)
except ClientError as e:
    logging.info(f'Unable to upload {output_name} to {dest_key}')
    logging.info(e)

def execute_program():
file_name = get_file_name()
file_data = get_file_data(file_name)
filtered_data = filter_file_data(file_data)
adjusted_file = prepare_file_for_upload(filtered_data)
upload_file = upload_file(adjusted_file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
execute_program()
```

Comment: Why the need to go through `StringIO`? You're writing to a CSV file anyway, so why not just write it directly?

Comment: @irene I wasnt sure if I could write directly to s3, but I just tested the following and based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38154040/save-dataframe-to-csv-directly-to-s3-python) and it worked: 
    'csv_buffer = StringIO()'
    'output_file = filtered_data.to_csv(csv_buffer)s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')'
    's3_resource.Object(dest_bucket,' output_name).put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())'

Comment: Glad you found a solution :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Following solution worked for me:

```
csv_buffer = StringIO()
output_file = filtered_data.to_csv(csv_buffer)
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_resource.Object(dest_bucket, output_name).put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
```

Answer (score 5):

When working with a BytesIO object, pay careful attention to the order of operations. In your code, you instantiate the BytesIO object and then fill it via a call to `to_csv()`. So far so good. But one thing to manage when working with a BytesIO object that is different from a file workflow is the stream position.

After writing data to the stream, the stream position is at the end of the stream. If you try to write from that position, you will likely write nothing! The operation will complete leaving you scratching your head why no results are written to S3. Add a call to `seek()` with the argument `0` to your function. Here is a demo program that demonstrates:

```
from io import BytesIO
import boto3
import pandas
from pandas import util
df = util.testing.makeMixedDataFrame()
s3_resource = boto3.resource("s3")
buffer = BytesIO()
df.to_csv(buffer, sep=",", index=False, mode="wb", encoding="UTF-8")

# The following call to `tell()` returns the stream position. 0 is the beginning of the file.
df.tell()
>> 134

# Reposition stream to the beginning by calling `seek(0)` before uploading
df.seek(0)
s3_r.Object("test-bucket", "test_df_from_resource.csv").put(Body=buffer.getvalue())
```

You should get a response similar to the following (with actual values)

```
>> {'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'request-id-value',
'HostId': '###########',
  'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
  'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amz-id-2': '############',
   'x-amz-request-id': '00000',
   'date': 'Tue, 31 Aug 2021 00:00:00 GMT',
   'x-amz-server-side-encryption': 'value',
   'etag': '"xxxx"',
   'server': 'AmazonS3',
   'content-length': '0'},
  'RetryAttempts': 0},
 'ETag': '"xxxx"',
 'ServerSideEncryption': 'value'}
```

Changing the code to move the stream position should solve the issues you were facing. It is also worth mentioning, Pandas [had a bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/35129) that caused unexpected behavior when writing to a bytes object. It was fixed and the sample I provided assumes you are running a version of Python greater than 3.8 and a version of Pandas greater than 1.3.2. Further information on IO can be found in the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html).