# Writing Pandas dataframe.groupby results to S3 bucket

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, bytesio

I have a large dataframe I am trying to break into smaller piece and write to a csv file in S3.  For testing purposes I have the groupby size set very low, but the concept is the same.  Here is the code I have:

```
if not submittingdata.empty:
    for i, g in submittingdata.groupby(df.index // 200):
        data = BytesIO()
        g.to_csv(data)
        s3_client.upload_fileobj(
            data,
            Bucket='some-magic-bucket',
            Key=f'file_prep_{i}.csv'
        )
```

The chunks are working correctly and the files are all being created as intended, but they are all empty.  Not sure what I am missing. My understanding is that the g.to_csv(data) should be writing the csv body to the BytesIO object, which is then what I'm using to write to the file.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding that?

Comment: Does this help? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50959593/write-pandas-dataframe-to-csv-stringio-instead-of-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following Patryks suggestion above I was able to find a piece of code that works.  Using Resource rather than client in boto3 and then writing to the body of a put from the BytesIO buffer I was able to get files populated with values.  The working code is:

```
if not submittingdata.empty:
    for i, g in submittingdata.groupby(df.index // 200):
        data = BytesIO()
        g.to_csv(data)
        s3_resource.Object(
            'some-magic-bucket',
            f'file_prep_{i}.csv'
        ).put(
            Body=data.getvalue()
        )
```