# NotImplementedError: Text mode not supported, use mode='wb' and manage bytes in s3fs

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker, python-s3fs

I know that there are a similar question but it is more general and not specific of this package. I am saving a pandas dataframe within a Sagemaker Jupyter notebook into a csv in S3 as follow:

```
df.to_csv('s3://bucket/key/file.csv', index=False)
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
NotImplementedError: Text mode not supported, use mode='wb' and manage bytes
```

The code more or less is that I read a csv from S3, make some preprocessing on it and then saves it to S3. I can read csv from S3 successfully with:

```
df.read_csv('s3://bucket/key/file.csv')
```

The object that I am trying to save to S3 is indeed a *pandas.core.frame.DataFrame*

In the notebook I can see using `!pip show package` that I have pandas 0.24.2 and s3fs 0.1.5.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you add more of your code to provide some context?

Comment: Perhaps a common problem in Pandas 0.24.2? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38154040/save-dataframe-to-csv-directly-to-s3-python/56275519#comment103490289_56275519

Comment: @Jamie I have added a little explanation, hope is enough

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack That's interesting, thanks

Comment: And https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8508#issuecomment-559248732 suggests it's fixed in 0.25.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you Please try

```
df.to_csv("s3://bucket/key/file.csv", index=False, mode='wb')
```

It should fix your error. The default mode is **w** which writes in the file system as text and not bytes. Where as s3 expects the data to be bytes. hence you have to specify mode as **wb**(write bytes) while writing the dataframe as csv to the filesystem.

Comment: Then it throws me the error TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'. It is weird because I have been using a lot s3fs to save csvs with pandas to s3 and I have never had to explicitly put mode = 'wb'

Comment: I am getting the same problem today. """ TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' """

Comment: Anyone know what's going on? Did AWS change something?

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem.

The cause seems to be having an old version of Pandas. Run

```
!pip install --upgrade pandas
```

in your Jupyter Notebook.

The reason you might have an old version of Pandas is if you shut down and then restarted your AWS machine - the AWS environments have older versions of Pandas (That is what happened to me). This problem was [fixed last year](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8508#issuecomment-559248732).