# with python, is there a way to load a polars dataframe directly into an s3 bucket as parquet

Tags: python, amazon-s3, parquet, python-polars

looking for something like this:

[Save Dataframe to csv directly to s3 Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38154040/save-dataframe-to-csv-directly-to-s3-python)

the api shows these arguments:
https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.write_parquet.html

but i'm not sure how to convert the df into a stream...

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for is [`s3fs`](https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#s3fs.core.S3File).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Untested, since I don't have an AWS account**

You could use [`s3fs.S3File`](https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#s3fs.core.S3File) like this:

```
import polars as pl
import s3fs

fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=True)  # picks up default credentials
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "foo": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "bar": [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        "ham": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
    }
)
with fs.open('my-bucket/dataframe-dump.parquet', mode='wb') as f:
    df.write_parquet(f)
```

Basically `s3fs` gives you an [`fsspec`](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) conformant file object, which polars knows how to use because `write_parquet` accepts any regular file or streams.

If you want to manage your S3 connection more granularly, you can construct as `S3File` object from the `botocore` connection (see the docs linked above).

Comment: this definitely works, im not sure what i was thinking not opening the file first before trying `df.write_parquet(f)` you also need to use 'wb'.  thank you.  any reason to use s3fs instead of boto3? havent used this one before.

Comment: @rndom Using something like s3fs gives you the flexibility to not care  what you are passing. e.g. you could easily pass a local file for testing, but run on S3 in production without changing your code.  Achieving that with boto3 yourself might require a lot of implementation on your part.  Does boto3 offer a file like API? (I fixed the mode in the answer)

Comment: when you use boto3 with something like `put_object` aws returns a response.  with s3fs i don't get anything like that, which i can figure out.  it would be great to use boto3 as a context manager, but i guess that's why s3fs uses https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ ?

Comment: Ya, pretty much.  It's an abstraction so that you can treat your blobs like files on a filesystem.  Then you don't have to wait for a response like boto3, instead you would expect `s3fs` succeed or raise an appropriate exception (or log).  You could look at the source to understand the behaviour better.