# Error when using pandas .to_csv function to upload to S3. "Anonymous access is forbidden for this operation"

Tags: pandas, amazon-s3, boto

I'm getting and error "Anonymous access is forbidden for this operation" when trying to use the df.to_csv function.

```
df.to_csv("s3://testdatateam1/test6.csv",
          storage_options={'key': 'key here',
                           'secret': 'secret here})
```

I've been able to use boto3 to read and write files from local using these credentials, and also a session token. But I need to write files from a pandas dataframe. I did read that pandas uses boto not boto3 which I also have imported.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40615630/530160) ?

Comment: @NickODell I have but I'm getting "Unable to locate credentials".

I have my credentials like this

client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='',
aws_secret_access_key='',
aws_session_token='')